# Ember returns an array when a single record is expected

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to load an edit form in a nested route. When I hit the URL for editing a company, /companies/87/edit, I get the edit template but instead of a single model I get: DS.RecordArray:ember314. It's an array with the one model object I want.

I noticed that ember314 is the same array getting used in the model of the companies template. I tried having CompanyEditRoute's model return {} and I can see that change reflected on the template. I'm not sure how to get only the model I want, not inside of an array.

**EDIT**

It looks like the nested routes are just picking up the model array off of the main route. This is strange because I confirmed each Route's model method is being called when the appropriate URL is hit.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('companies', function() {
    this.resource('company', { path: ':company_id' }, function() {
      this.route('edit');
    });
  });  
});


App.CompanyEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Company.find(params.company_id);
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({into: 'application', outlet: 'modal'});
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the value of params.company_id. I suspect it's `undefined` so you're basically calling `App.Company.find()` again, which is probably also your model for 'companines'

Comment: You are correct! How would I access the company_id in my edit route in this case?

Comment: Nice catch Trek, modelFor('company')

Comment: @TrekGlowacki, you were correct and I'm able to get my model now for both routes. Now I'm completely confused about how routes work. Why does CompanyIndexRoute#model require params, they're set to {}, and the model for company is magically accessible for the url /companies/25? I have access to the correct company by id but it's not set anywhere, and I'd expect it to be set on the CompanyIndexRoute since it has the dynamic segment in Router.

Comment: The parameters get passed only to route that defines them. You can access the parent's model with `modelFor('company')` or, if you really want to trigger another find, `model` has two args: `params` and `transition`. The transition contains more all the params required to enter this nesting.

Comment: @TrekGlowacki, what you explained makes perfect sense to me. What's confusing is that the dynamic segment is defined on the CompanyIndex resource but isn't available via params on the CompanyIndexRoute. Instead CompanyIndexRoute has to use modelFor('company') to access the model.

Comment: You might want to download the Ember Inspector. It'll highlight what the route is and where dynamic segments are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch, but when you use render in the renderTemplate hook you aren't specifying the controller, so it might just be throwing away your controller and using the parent controller.

Look up the documentation, but I think it's something like this

```
renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
  this.render({into: 'application', outlet: 'modal', controller: controller});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, kingpin2k. I verified via the Ember Inspector that the correct controller is being attached. If I hit /companies/2 the company.index controller is used and if I hit /companies/2/edit the company.edit controller is used. In both cases, it's getting a DS.RecordArray for the model.